# не работает таск для gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, task

Начал осваивать gulp попробовал написать собственный таск. Начал с простого, но не срабатывает, в чем я ошибся?

```js
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    var informCol1 = new ('Author', 'Project name', 'version', 'Start project');
    var informCol2 = new ('Forest Gump', 'Modus Versus', '1.0.0');
    informCol2[3] = new Date();
    console.log(informCol1 + ':' + informCol2);
})
```

вот код ошибки

```
PS C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus> gulp myTask
[23:11:01] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\gulpfile.js
[23:11:01] Starting 'myTask'...
[23:11:01] 'myTask' errored after 25 ms
[23:11:01] TypeError: ((("Author" , "Project name") , "version") , "Start project") is not a constructor
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\gulpfile.js:51:22)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\Work\Test Sliceart\ModusVersus\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Comment: а как вы ее запускаете?

Comment: через команду gulp myTask

Comment: если просто что нибудь выведу через console.log, то срабатывает

Comment: Может вывод ошибки в вопрос добавите :) Мы не экстрасенсы.

Comment: В task'е на сколько знаю console.log нельзя так делать.

Comment: срабатывает же)

Comment: А, так вы new чего делаете то? new Array()?

Comment: в тасках можно делать console.log, если есть console ^)/ Обычно вроде бы есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пропустили именование функции. Нельзя делать new ()

```
 var informCol1 = new ('Author', 'Project name', 'version', 'Start project');
```

Добавьте название функции

Comment: не совсем понял?)я же массив таким образом объявил

Comment: @nirolo1 так массивы не объявляются. 
массивы объявляются так: var arr = ['test', 'test1', 'test2'];

Comment: сейчас исправлю попробую

Comment: или new Array('1', '2', '3')